# Jquery autocomplete - how modify returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#au').length <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    var $project = $('#au');
    $project.autocomplete({
        minLength: 4,

        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                data: {term: request.term},
                url: '/Movies/ajax/',

                success: function (data) {
                    if (isNaN($('#au').val())) {

                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {

                                label: item.Movies__name + " " + "(" + item.Movies__id + ")",
                                value: item.Movies__name
                            }
                        }));
                    } else {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Movies__id + " " + "(" + item.Movies__name + ")",
                                value: item.Movies__id
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#au").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#au").submit();
        },


        create: function (event, ui) {
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {

        }
    });

});
```

This code works fine. Basicly when You type in form "Alie", you will get

Alien(22)
Aliens2(32)
Aliens3(43)

Or when you type Id istead of movie name, you will get:

(22)Alien
(22)Other and so on....

So this code returns list of data - movie and id.

And now i want, to have first result without id, so when You type movie name like "Alie" you will get:

Alien
Alien(22)
Aliens(32)

First match without id.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response($.map(data, function (item, i) {
      return {
         label: item.Movies__name + (i != 0 ? " (" + item.Movies__id + ")" : ""),
         value: item.Movies__name
      }
}));
```

Use i for index in map function. If 0, you don't show id.